# layout design suggestion for modal popup

Tags: responsive-design, user-experience

I am looking for layout design suggestion for one of my screens.

I have a modal popup window which displays the customers information in tabbed layout which means one tab per customer. each tab has 3 accordions out of which 2 accordions have tables(grid).

Now the requirement is to compare the customer data side by side instead of using tabs. we can have maximum of 4 customers.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you are going for:
[Layout diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTK3B.jpg)

I suggest you use the `<table>` tag for that. Each table column (`<td>`) will represent one customer.

I provided you with my example below.

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#modal {
  width: 80%;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 80%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

#customer_table {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75%;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

tr:first-child td {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #5a5a5a;
  color: white;
}

td {
  border-left: solid #5a5a5a 1px;
  border-right: solid #5a5a5a 1px;
  border-bottom: solid #5a5a5a 1px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="modal">
    <h2>Customer table</h2>
    <table id="customer_table">
      <tr>
        <td>Customer 1</td>
        <td>Customer 2</td>
        <td>Customer 3</td>
        <td>Customer 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Customer data</td>
        <td>Customer data</td>
        <td>Customer data</td>
        <td>Customer data</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```